# Customized wizard that creates fragment

Tags: eclipse-plugin, osgi, wizard, osgi-bundle

I am a beginner in plugin development. I need to add a fragment project type using my customized Wizard. I could manage the part with `<extention>` tags in `plugin.xml` and the wizard lunch from `File->New->Other->` so the default wizard appears.

The idea is that I need to customize it and make it able to create fragment files after I click on the next button.

"which is my own extension". What is the method called when that button is clicked ? Can anyone please explain?

```
File->New->Other->"my wizard"-->Fragment Project->Next
[Done_Bar//////////////////////-----------------------]
```

Comment: You should not create anything until the user clicks 'Finish' otherwise 'Cancel' will not be able to clean up properly.

Comment: I know but is there a way to acces to the source code of the monitor wizard that creates projects ?

Comment: See [Eclipse Source Code](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/EclipseCodeAccess/article.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can copy code to create a fragment from here - https://github.com/Nasdanika/server/blob/master/org.nasdanika.workspace.wizard/src/org/nasdanika/workspace/wizard/AbstractWorkspaceWizard.java